# What is the best way to create an Angular form containing components?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am building a very long form. The form in question has 3 main sections, and for maintenance reasons, I would like to clean the template by using 3 components.

The problem is that when you update a component's input, the form model containing those components does not update, and thus, does not validate using Angular's "native" form validator.

I thought of "sharing" data from those components to the parent form using a service, but that doesn't give me the validator.

I then thought that I could use component bindings to pass the form's model, but that sounds like too much work, or something dirty.

So what is the best practice for executing this?

Pseudo code example:

```
<form>
    <component-1/> <!-- how do I get data out of there, and into the form model -->
    <component-2/> <!-- how do I validate the inputs inside the components using angular -->
    <component-3/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you can use **angular-material** uı components framework and "**ng-messages**" for validation.

Comment: I would prefer not to rely on a plugin.

Comment: "when you update a component's input, the form model containing those components does not update"  ... what do you mean by that exactly?  posting some sample code of how you have your form + component templates + bindings setup is probably going to be necessary to get a helpful response here.

Comment: I can give any sample code, my question is to actually find out what is the best approach!

Comment: And components have isolate scopes. That is why when you write in an input the parent scope (the form scope) isn't updated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I experimented a little with this and found this out.

Parent form:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="$ctrl.submit(form)>
    <component-1></component-1>
</form>
```

Component-1 form elements:

```
<fieldset ng-form="child-form">
    <input
        type="text"
        name="first-name"
        id="first-name"
        ng-model="$ctrl.sharedService.formData.name">
</fieldset>
```

There is no "native" way to "sync" the model from the child component to the parent's component unless you use `=` binding (which is apparently bad practice for components, as they should be stateless, or if you want to mimic Angular 2 components).

That said, when you submit the parent form, Angular will give you the form object that contains the children forms (the property will be the name in `ng-form` of your component).

This allows you to check for `$valid`, `$error`, etc...

Finally, so save, or sync the component input values, we can save the form input values on a shared service object which can be used to compose the `$http` call to save the values to your backend.